# AngularFire2 subsequent filter does not filter the list

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm pretty new to Angular 2 so this may be really simple. I've been googling a while with no luck. I'm pulling player data from Firebase using AF2 then trying to filter the list to just 1. I think my code shows what I'm attempting...

**player-fb.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class PlayerFbService {
    players$: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    player$: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

    constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
        this.players$ = this.af.database.list('/player');
        this.players$.subscribe(
            val => {
                console.log('players$', val);
            }
        );
    }

    filterByHandle(handle: string) {
        const handleSubject = new Subject();
        this.players$ = this.af.database.list('/player', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'handle',
                equalTo: handleSubject
            }
        });
        handleSubject.next(handle);
    }

}
```

The service works, I see my initial list of 2 players, but when I click the button, nothing happens. The code is def called and the handle sent in is one of the handle values in the list, but the list stays the same. No change.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

Here is my template for the component that calls the service...

**player.component.html**

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let player of players$ | async">
        {{ player | json }}
    </li>
</ul>
<button (click)="filterByHandle('professorkill')">Filter</button>
```

**player.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PlayerFbService } from './../../service/fb/player-fb.service';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-player',
    templateUrl: './player.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./player.component.css']
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {
    players$: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

    constructor(private playerService: PlayerFbService) {
        this.players$ = this.playerService.players$;
    }

    filterByHandle(handle: string) {
        this.playerService.filterByHandle(handle);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Comment: This code block is slightly confusing, are you attempting to filter the data in your observable when the filterByHandle() method is called?

Comment: @DevonGermano Correct :-)

Comment: Is the list in firebase that you wish to filter /player? Or /players?

Comment: You've not shared enough code. The `players$` in your injectable service cannot be used directly in the template, so to what the template's `players$` refers is unclear.

Comment: @cartant Added all 3 code files to OP. Do I need to add any more? The code does initially work. I do see the players$ list on the page showing 2 player records. When you click the filter button, the list should change to just the one player matched by `handle = 'professorkill'`. This part does not work and I'm not sure how to fix.

Comment: I got it working, posted code below. Thank you everyone for the replies. I greatly appreciate the help. If you see something weird in my code, please post the right/better way to code it. I have a LOT to learn yet :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like the parts missing in the service were repeating the subscriber and building an array to display records on the main component template. Following is updated/working code. NOTE: Don't forget to add your service to app.module.ts and then add it to the providers array.

```
<!--
===============================================================================
src/app/admin/player/player.component.html
-->
<br>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let player of players">
        {{ player | json }}
    </li>
</ul>
<button (click)="filterByHandle('professorkill')">Filter</button>


// ============================================================================
// src/app/admin/player/player.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PlayerFbService } from './../../service/fb/player-fb.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-player',
    templateUrl: './player.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./player.component.css']
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {
    players: any[];

    constructor(private playerService: PlayerFbService) {
        this.players = playerService.players;
    }

    filterByHandle(handle: string) {
        this.playerService.filterByHandle(handle);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}


// ============================================================================
// src/app/service/fb/player-fb.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class PlayerFbService {
    public players: any[] = [];
    private playerList$: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

    constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
        this.playerList$ = this.af.database.list('/player');
        this.playerList$.subscribe(val => { this.buildPlayers(val); });
    }

    public filterByHandle(handle: string) {
        this.playerList$ = this.af.database.list('/player', {
            query: { orderByChild: 'handle', equalTo: handle }
        });
        this.playerList$.subscribe(val => { this.buildPlayers(val); });
    }

    private buildPlayers(val: any[]) {
        this.players.length = 0;
        val.forEach(element => {
            this.players.push(element);
        });
    }
}
```